# Use PHP to play audio on server

Tags: php, shell, nginx, audio

I am trying to use PHP to play a sound **ON SERVER SIDE** once someone visits my webpage.
It's running on Nginx/Php5 (raspberry pi).

This is how I'm trying to do it:

I have executed command:

```
sudo usermod -aG audio www-data
```

The php file:

```
<?php
$audio = shell_exec('sh play.sh');
echo $audio;
?>
```

But it results nothing.

Running 'id' command with the same method results:

```
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),29(audio),44(video)
```

I don't know if its relevant but:

```
ls -lah /dev/snd

drwxr-xr-x   3 root root      160 Oct 26 17:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root     3.5K Oct 26 17:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       60 Oct 26 17:22 by-path
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  0 Oct 26 17:22 controlC0
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 16 Oct 26 17:22 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 17 Oct 26 17:22 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  1 Oct 26 17:22 seq
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 33 Oct 26 17:22 timer
```

Executing the following command plays the file properly:

```
sudo -u www-data play ding.mp3
```

But using the following one:

```
sudo -u www-data sh play.sh
```

Results:

```
Sorry, user www-data is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/play /var/www/ding.mp3' as www-data on raspberrypi.
```

The script contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/play '/var/www/ding.mp3'
```

Any other command in that script is executed properly.
Anyone could give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the solution.

The solution was to delete "sudo -u www-data" part from the shell script.
Now it contains only:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/play '/var/www/ding.mp3'
```

I leave it here, so maybe someone will find it useful in the future.

Comment: Why were you using sudo in the first place?

Comment: I tought that will eliminate any permission problem of playing the sound. I was wrong.